# How to fix xampp cant run apache

Tags: xampp

How to fix it 
Help me 
helppppppp
pleaseeeeeee

```
3:30:42 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:30:42 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:30:42 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:30:42 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:30:42 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:30:42 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:30:42 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the port of Apache server

If you have opened the skype or Team viewer This issue will appear

Comment: how to exit skype